# How to Execute Sonar on TeamCity

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build configuration with multiple steps, and I want the last step to be Sonar. The steps are like this:

1. Maven `clean deploy -DskipITs`
2. Maven `verify`
3. Maven `sonar:sonar`

For all I know that should work, because Sonar doesn't need to compile the sources in the same Maven reactor. And it does work sometimes. Other times I get cryptic error message like:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project org.acme.project: Maven session does not declare a top level project -> [Help 1]
```

OR

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project org.acme.project.build: Not inside a Git work tree: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9aeba6ee3e5dd34c\org.acme.project.it -> [Help 1]
```

*(The project `org.acme.project.it` is of course the last module, so Sonar has analyzed everything else before.)*

I checked the log and compared it with the working builds. The difference for **Not inside a Git work tree** is the addition of the following line:

```
[INFO] SCM provider for this project is: git
```

For **Maven session does not declare a top level project** it fails immediately after calling the Maven Sonar plug-in:

```
[09:55:46][Step 3/3] [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) @ org.acme.project ---
[09:55:46][Step 3/3] [INFO] User cache: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
[09:55:46][Step 3/3] [INFO] SonarQube version: 6.7.1
[09:55:46][Step 3/3] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project org.acme.project: Maven session does not declare a top level project
```

Both error message have very little information and google search results for both are sparse.

However if I use the Maven command `clean verify sonar:sonar` everything works. (But since the error messages are not reproducible that could be a coincidence.)

How do I create a reproducible Sonar build in TeamCity?

Comment: Well, the first strange thing is that you call verify after deploy. Can you provide a full build log?

Comment: @Frank It's not that strange in a world where developers need to work with an artifact immediately and the integration tests need some hours to complete. I checked the build logs and compared them to the working ones, the differences are in the question. Do you need more? The entire build log is 3000 lines long. I doubt anybody will read it (and I don't want to anonymize it).

Comment: Ok, from the input I can not see exactly what leads to this failure, but here are some things to consider: When SQ mojo is started it gets a MavenSession injected by maven runtime. It then looks into the session's projects (aka modules, sorted according to reactor build order) and then checks for every project if it's the project in the execution root, meaning the folder the pom.xml is located which you specify by -f parameter or, if nothing is specified, the folder you start mvn from. If by any means there is no such project (e.g. if you use -pl option), you will get that above error.